# How to slice the model with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to use three.js to implement this dynamic slicing effect similar to the GIF picture.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pandabajie/3d/master/slice.gif

How do I do it?
[links here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJj95.gif)

Comment: have you looked into `Material.clippingPlanes`?

Comment: See https://threejs.org/examples/?q=clipping

Comment: I made a successful attempt，Thanks all very much